# SQL Server Management Studio: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I am trying to write a complex query by joining info from 3 tables. However, I am getting the error below:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    DailyOnhand.[Country Code], 
    DailyOnhand.Item, 
    DailyOnhand.[DTP USD], 
    DailyOnhand.[OH Value USD OP], 
    DailyOnhand.[OH Quantity], 
    DailyOnhand.[Onhand Type],
    DailyOnhand.[FE SSO],
    DailyOnhand.[Newest Job Number],
    SO.[SO Number],
FROM 
    [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].DailyOnhand
WHERE 
    DailyOnhand.[Pole] IN ('EU')
LEFT JOIN 
    [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].AllSO SO ON AllPO.Item = SO.[item] 
                                        AND AllPO.[Newest Job Number] = SO.[Job Number] 
                                        AND AllPO.[FE SSO] = SO.[FE SSO]

UNION ALL

SELECT
    PO.[Receiving Country Code] as [Country Code],  
    '' AS Item, 
    '' AS [DTP USD], 
    SUM(PO.[Total Price OP USD]) AS [OH Value USD OP],
    '' AS [OH Quantity],
    'GIT' AS [Onhand Type],
    '' AS [FE SSO],
    '' AS [FE Name],
    '' AS [Newest Job Number],
    '' AS [SO Number],
FROM 
    [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].AllPO as PO
WHERE 
    (1=1)
    AND PO.[Linked SO Org] LIKE ('[ARUM][0-9][0-9]')
    AND PO.[Receiving Org] LIKE ('[R][0-9][0-9]')
    AND ((PO.[Receiving Org] NOT IN ('R34') AND CAST((GetDate()-PO.[Creation Date]) AS INT)<30)
    OR (PO.[Receiving Org] IN ('R34') AND CAST((GetDate()-PO.[Creation Date]) AS INT)<45))
    AND PO.[DW CLOSED CODE] = 'Open'
    AND PO.[Linked SO Intransit Qty]>0
GROUP BY 
    PO.[Receiving Org], PO.[Receiving Country Name], PO.[Receiving Country Code]
```

Moreover, if I move the below part somewhere else like right behind of last `FROM` clause, I am getting the error of

> The multi-part identifier could not be bound for "SO.SO Number", "AllPO.Item", "AllPO.Newest Job Number","AllPO.FE SSO"

```
LEFT JOIN 
    [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].AllSO SO ON AllPO.Item = SO.[item] 
                                        AND AllPO.[Newest Job Number] = SO.[Job Number]  
                                        AND AllPO.[FE SSO] = SO.[FE SSO]
```

Comment: you have a comma after last item in select list in each union parts

Comment: _dangling comma_ --> `SO.[SO Number],`  ... remove it

Comment: Also move first `WHERE` clause after first `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: more: `join` should be before `where`

Comment: There are multiple syntactical and logical issues going on here.

Comment: Read & act on [mcve]. Cut your code down until it compiles & runs correctly then add incrementally. What did googling the error message tell you?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some corrections to your query. There were multiple syntax issues.

```
SELECT 
 DailyOnhand.[Country Code], 
 DailyOnhand.Item, 
 DailyOnhand.[DTP USD], 
 DailyOnhand.[OH Value USD OP], 
 DailyOnhand.[OH Quantity], 
 DailyOnhand.[Onhand Type],
 DailyOnhand.[FE SSO],
 DailyOnhand.[Newest Job Number],
 SO.[SO Number]                                                     --removed comma

 FROM [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].DailyOnhand


 LEFT JOIN [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].AllSO SO
                  ON AllPO.Item = SO.[item] 
                  AND AllPO.[Newest Job Number] = SO.[Job Number] 
                  AND AllPO.[FE SSO] = SO.[FE SSO]
 WHERE DailyOnhand.[Pole] In ('EU')                                 --moved this

 UNION ALL
    SELECT
    PO.[Receiving Country Code] as [Country Code],  
    '' AS Item, 
    '' AS [DTP USD], 
    SUM(PO.[Total Price OP USD]) AS [OH Value USD OP],
    '' AS [OH Quantity],
    'GIT' AS [Onhand Type],
    '' AS [FE SSO],
    '' AS [FE Name],
    '' AS [Newest Job Number],
    '' AS [SO Number]                                               --removed comma

    FROM [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].AllPO as PO

    WHERE 
    (1=1)                                                           --this is pointless
    AND PO.[Linked SO Org] LIKE ('[ARUM][0-9][0-9]')
    AND PO.[Receiving Org] LIKE ('[R][0-9][0-9]')
    AND ((PO.[Receiving Org] NOT IN ('R34') AND CAST((GetDate()-PO.[Creation Date]) AS INT)<30)  --No need for IN since you use a single value
    OR (PO.[Receiving Org] IN ('R34') AND CAST((GetDate()-PO.[Creation Date]) AS INT)<45))  --No need for IN since you use a single value
    AND PO.[DW CLOSED CODE] = 'Open'
    AND PO.[Linked SO Intransit Qty]>0

    GROUP BY PO.[Receiving Org],PO.[Receiving Country Name],PO.[Receiving Country Code] --you probably only need [Receiving Country Code]
```

Comment: I was also assuming they want the aggregate sorted to the end which as you know will usually happen when using UNION ALL but not always. +1 from me.

Comment: @SeanLange "Usually" means "not".

Answer (score 2):

The `LEFT JOIN` goes after the `FROM`. As others have noted the trailing commas has been removed.

Like below.

```
 SELECT 
        DailyOnhand.[Country Code], 
        DailyOnhand.Item, 
        DailyOnhand.[DTP USD], 
        DailyOnhand.[OH Value USD OP], 
        DailyOnhand.[OH Quantity], 
        DailyOnhand.[Onhand Type],
        DailyOnhand.[FE SSO],
        DailyOnhand.[Newest Job Number],
        SO.[SO Number]
    FROM 
        [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].DailyOnhand LEFT JOIN 
        [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].AllSO SO ON AllPO.Item = SO.[item] 
                                            AND AllPO.[Newest Job Number] = SO.[Job Number] 
                                            AND AllPO.[FE SSO] = SO.[FE SSO]
    WHERE 
        DailyOnhand.[Pole] IN ('EU')

UNION ALL

SELECT
    PO.[Receiving Country Code] as [Country Code],  
    '' AS Item, 
    '' AS [DTP USD], 
    SUM(PO.[Total Price OP USD]) AS [OH Value USD OP],
    '' AS [OH Quantity],
    'GIT' AS [Onhand Type],
    '' AS [FE SSO],
    '' AS [FE Name],
    '' AS [Newest Job Number],
    '' AS [SO Number]
FROM 
    [hce.com].[DATAMART].[dbo].AllPO as PO
WHERE 
    (1=1)
    AND PO.[Linked SO Org] LIKE ('[ARUM][0-9][0-9]')
    AND PO.[Receiving Org] LIKE ('[R][0-9][0-9]')
    AND ((PO.[Receiving Org] NOT IN ('R34') AND CAST((GetDate()-PO.[Creation Date]) AS INT)<30)
    OR (PO.[Receiving Org] IN ('R34') AND CAST((GetDate()-PO.[Creation Date]) AS INT)<45))
    AND PO.[DW CLOSED CODE] = 'Open'
    AND PO.[Linked SO Intransit Qty]>0
GROUP BY 
    PO.[Receiving Org], PO.[Receiving Country Name], PO.[Receiving Country Code]
```